# Sound not working after installing Ubuntu on iota360

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 with kernel 4.13.0-36-generic on my iota 360. I was warned that there would be sound issues and sure enough the sound doesn't work. I have reinstalled both ALSA and Pulseaudio. I have tried a host of different things, with and without Pulseaudio installed (just trying to ALSA on its own). I have no sound icon in the upper right hand corner. Without Pulseaudio, some of the errors were different but still no sound. I also looked in BIOS and couldn't see anything to do with sound. I'm just trying to get a grip of what's going on and would appreciate any help. Here is a list of outputs for all the different things I have seen suggested:

- amixer
- aplay -l
- aplay -L
- aplay sample.wav
- aplay -D plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=0 ~/sample.wav
- aplay -D hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=0 ~/sample.wav
- lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
- lspci
- sudo lshw
- sudo lshw -class sound
- dmesg | grep audio
- dmesg | grep lpe
- lsmod | grep snd
- inxi -A

```
>>> amixer
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
```

```
>>> aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 0: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 1: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 2: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
>>> aplay -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=Audio
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Front speakers
hdmi:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=1
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=2
    Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio, Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

I have a sample wav file and this is what I get when I 'aplay' it.

```
>>> aplay sample.wav
Playing WAVE 'sample.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
underrun!!! (at least 0.033 ms long)
underrun!!! (at least 0.017 ms long)
```

with no sound. This also happens when I do

```
>>> aplay -D default:CARD=Audio ~/sample.wav
ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Unknown parameters CARD=Audio
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default:CARD=Audio
aplay: main:722: audio open error: Invalid argument
```

```
>>> aplay -D plughw:CARD=Audio,DEV=0 ~/sample.wav
aplay: main:722: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

If I try some of the other devices, I get some errors:

```
>>> aplay -D hw:CARD=Audio,DEV=0 ~/sample.wav
aplay: main:722: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

Running

```
>>> lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
```

returns nothing.

```
>>> lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 36)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers (rev 36)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 36)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 36)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 36)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 36)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 36)
```

I also ran

```
>>> sudo lshw
iota                      
    description: Notebook
    product: IOTA2210 (20180326304)
    vendor: iOTA
    version: 1
    serial: EM134119719
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=IOTA2210 sku=20180326304 uuid=F29FCCDF-F527-E811-B1A7-B0DA79E17600
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: H8316-216B
       vendor: iOTA
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: Default string
       slot: Default string
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 8.18
          date: 05/26/2018
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 4032KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 28
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
             product: 00000000
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: A1_DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 8 bits
             clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2016-06-27 17:08+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18115) [empty]
             product: 00000000
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: A1_DIMM1
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 32
          slot: CPU Internal L1
          size: 224KiB
          capacity: 224KiB
          capabilities: internal write-back
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 33
          slot: CPU Internal L2
          size: 2MiB
          capacity: 2MiB
          capabilities: internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z8350  CPU @ 1.44GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 34
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Atom(TM) x5-Z8350 CPU @ 1.44GHz
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 484MHz
          capacity: 2400MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 80MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti retpoline spec_ctrl tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 36
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=iosf_mbi_pci
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 36
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:217 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
             description: Multimedia controller
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 36
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:91000000-913fffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
             version: 36
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:263 memory:9183b000-9183bfff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 36
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:215 memory:91800000-9180ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.13.0-36-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=7 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Mouse
                   product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: USB Keyboard
                   vendor: Hantick
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@1:2
                   version: 50.01
                   serial: NT16H-MEDION-US-20170601-VER:3.0
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Video
                   product: USB 2.0 PC Cam
                   vendor: Image Processor
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 0.05
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.13.0-36-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.13
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic:1
             description: Encryption controller
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 36
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_txe latency=0
             resources: irq:264 memory:91700000-917fffff memory:91600000-916fffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 36
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 58:b3:fc:11:96:7f
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs ip=192.168.1.1 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

```
>>> sudo lshw -class sound
  *-multimedia UNCLAIMED  
       description: Multimedia controller
       product: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       version: 36
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:91000000-913fffff
  *-usb:2
       description: Video
       product: USB 2.0 PC Cam
       vendor: Image Processor
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@1:4
       version: 0.05
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

```
>>> dmesg | grep audio
[    2.918575] [drm] HDaudio controller not detected, using LPE audio instead
[    6.159055] input: Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio HDMI/DP,pcm=0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/hdmi-lpe-audio/sound/card0/input5
[    6.159219] input: Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio HDMI/DP,pcm=1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/hdmi-lpe-audio/sound/card0/input6
[    6.159376] input: Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio HDMI/DP,pcm=2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/hdmi-lpe-audio/sound/card0/input7
[  375.884694] Modules linked in: bnep hci_uart btbcm serdev btqca btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic nls_iso8859_1 joydev intel_rapl intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm axp288_fuel_gauge axp288_charger irqbypass axp288_adc extcon_axp288 axp20x_pek punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul gpio_keys ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc uvcvideo aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper videobuf2_vmalloc cryptd videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 intel_cstate videobuf2_core input_leds hid_multitouch videodev media mei_txe snd_intel_sst_acpi lpc_ich snd_intel_sst_core processor_thermal_device mei snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform intel_soc_dts_iosf snd_hdmi_lpe_audio snd_soc_sst_match snd_soc_nau8824 snd_soc_rt5670 snd_seq_midi snd_soc_rt5645 snd_seq_midi_event mac_hid snd_soc_rt5640 extcon_intel_int3496 snd_rawmidi
[ 1320.661402] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211663.236:34): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.pulseaudio" pid=8044 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1321.044900] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211663.620:35): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.pulseaudio.config" pid=8045 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1321.089625] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211663.664:36): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.pulseaudio.pactl" pid=8046 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1321.471130] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211664.046:37): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.pulseaudio.paplay" pid=8047 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1321.512963] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211664.088:38): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.pulseaudio.parec" pid=8048 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1321.899794] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211664.475:39): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio" pid=8049 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1325.590203] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211668.165:42): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.pulseaudio.pactl" pid=8104 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1325.615777] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211668.191:43): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.pulseaudio.paplay" pid=8105 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1326.145532] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211668.720:44): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.pulseaudio.parec" pid=8107 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1326.159051] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211668.734:45): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.pulseaudio" pid=8109 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1326.161066] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211668.736:46): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.pulseaudio.config" pid=8110 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1326.168965] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211668.744:47): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio" pid=8111 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1327.823790] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211670.399:50): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio" name="/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_vendor" pid=8172 comm="pulseaudio" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ 1327.838949] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211670.414:51): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio" pid=8172 comm="pulseaudio" capability=2  capname="dac_read_search"
[ 1327.838959] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211670.414:52): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio" pid=8172 comm="pulseaudio" capability=1  capname="dac_override"
[ 1328.070160] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211670.645:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio" name="/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_vendor" pid=8172 comm="pulseaudio" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ 1331.176406] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211673.752:65): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio" name="/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_vendor" pid=8387 comm="pulseaudio" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

```
>>> dmesg | grep lpe
[    6.159055] input: Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio HDMI/DP,pcm=0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/hdmi-lpe-audio/sound/card0/input5
[    6.159219] input: Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio HDMI/DP,pcm=1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/hdmi-lpe-audio/sound/card0/input6
[    6.159376] input: Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio HDMI/DP,pcm=2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/hdmi-lpe-audio/sound/card0/input7
[    9.382625] audit: type=1400 audit(1585210352.479:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=760 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.445470] audit: type=1400 audit(1585210352.542:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="webbrowser-app//oxide_helper" pid=763 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  375.884694] Modules linked in: bnep hci_uart btbcm serdev btqca btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic nls_iso8859_1 joydev intel_rapl intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm axp288_fuel_gauge axp288_charger irqbypass axp288_adc extcon_axp288 axp20x_pek punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul gpio_keys ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc uvcvideo aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper videobuf2_vmalloc cryptd videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 intel_cstate videobuf2_core input_leds hid_multitouch videodev media mei_txe snd_intel_sst_acpi lpc_ich snd_intel_sst_core processor_thermal_device mei snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform intel_soc_dts_iosf snd_hdmi_lpe_audio snd_soc_sst_match snd_soc_nau8824 snd_soc_rt5670 snd_seq_midi snd_soc_rt5645 snd_seq_midi_event mac_hid snd_soc_rt5640 extcon_intel_int3496 snd_rawmidi
[  375.884790]  fdp_i2c dw_dmac r8723bs(CE) fdp dw_dmac_core snd_soc_rl6231 intel_hid nci sparse_keymap cfg80211 snd_soc_core intel_soc_pmic_bxtwc snd_seq nfc intel_pmc_ipc snd_compress ac97_bus kxcjk_1013 snd_pcm_dmaengine rfkill_gpio axp20x_i2c snd_pcm snd_seq_device axp20x silead goodix industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf industrialio intel_cht_int33fe snd_timer snd 8250_dw soundcore spi_pxa2xx_platform tpm_crb intel_int0002_vgpio dptf_power acpi_pad soc_button_array int3406_thermal int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 overlay hid_generic usbhid mmc_block i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm video i2c_hid hid pwm_lpss_platform pwm_lpss sdhci_acpi sdhci
[ 1324.994413] audit: type=1400 audit(1585211667.569:41): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/8689/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=8102 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

```
>>> lsmod | grep snd
snd_intel_sst_acpi     16384  0
snd_intel_sst_core     77824  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform   102400  1 snd_intel_sst_core
snd_hdmi_lpe_audio     24576  0
snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_nau8824        53248  0
snd_soc_rt5670        131072  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_soc_rt5645        147456  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_soc_rt5640        118784  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  3 snd_soc_rt5670,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_rt5645
snd_soc_core          229376  5 snd_soc_rt5670,snd_soc_nau8824,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_rt5645
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm                98304  8 snd_soc_rt5670,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_soc_nau8824,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_rt5645,snd_soc_core
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  9 snd_compress,snd_seq,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_timer,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_device,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

```
>>> inxi -A
Audio:     Card Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio driver: HdmiLpeAudio Sound: ALSA v: k4.13.0-36-generic
```

Comment: I don't know your device, but 4.13 is an EOL kernel for Ubuntu, and is neither of the two supported kernels for 16.04 LTS; have you tried the two supported 16.04 kernels?

Comment: When I installed Ubuntu, because it is CherryTrail hardware, there were issues that meant that the system kept suspending. I changed kernel from 4.15 to 4.13 and that problem stopped. That's why I'm using the older version.